# Porque debo poner la etiqueta script debajo de la etiqueta del canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas

Estaba tranquilo trabajando con el Canvas hasta que me salió el error Cannot read properties of null (reading 'getContext') para solucionarlo tuve que poner la etiqueta script debajo de la del canvas¿PORQUE HAY QUE ENLAZAR EL ARCHIVO JAVASCRIP DEBAJO DEL CANVAS?

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Porque seguramente el script trata de acceder al canvas cuando todavía no existe y se soluciona al poner la etiqueta debajo. Lo mejor sería ejecutar el código cuando el [DOM se haya cargado](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/DOMContentLoaded_event)

Answer (score 0):

Sencillamente se lee de arriba hacia abajo, si tu pides tener el contexto de algo que no se ha creado ahora, y luego de pedir se crea, no tiene logica, esto es logica del flujo de lectura

Comment: Esto no provee una respuesta a la pregunta.  En cuanto tengas suficiente [reputación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) podrás [comentar en cualquier publicación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). Es mejor [dar respuestas que no requieran clarificación de la persona que hizo la pregunta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/586/). - [Desde revisión](/review/late-answers/395352)

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).